# Change Visual Studio 2022 Team Explorer default behavior

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, team-explorer

I used to modify a registry key to change the behavior of VS 2019 and older, so when I add a task to a Team Explorer Check-in (TFS) it automatically set the action to **associate** instead of **resolve**. But in VS 2022 it doesn't work anymore.

I have used Procmon to see where in the registry the value is pulled from (see screenshot).  It should be from :

`\REGISTRY\A\{f50c8c4a-61b8-5c67-cfa8-3be1e1ea5def}\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_bb27d245\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior\ResolveAsDefaultCheckinAction`

But I don't know where to modify that value. I tried to set it in `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior` but it doesn't work. This key is now ignored.

Has anyone an idea of where I should change this value ? Also, there must be something I miss here, because this type of registry path are new to me.

[image: Registry Key Process Monitor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you can simply access it in the options...

[image]